# How can I make a Multilanguage chatbot that I can ask my bot to switch language in dialogflow?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have made 2 languages chatbot but can't switch language in my chatbot. It only answers back in my default language.

Comment: This question needs a little more detail. What have you tried so far? Do you have some example code to show? Is there some output or replication steps ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.